# My sentence cuts off halfway through whilst I want it to be one sentence

Tags: html, css, tumblr-themes

Somehow when I write the description of my theme it cuts the sentence half-way through,

"Pray you, love, 
Remember"

Instead of

"Pray you, love, remember"

([http://imgur.com/a/n3fOl](https://imgur.com/a/n3fOl))

This is the CSS I found related to this.

```
#description {
height: 55px;
width: 100%;

overflow: none;
line-height: 1.2;
display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
align-items: center;
}

#description > p {
margin: auto;
}
```

Entire HTML [here](http://view-source:https://actualophelia.tumblr.com/)

Thank you guys so much! Sorry it's such a trivial question but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: The link to your page isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to implicitly set a break point in the HTML using < br / > when you want the newline to start, or you can do one of the following:

1. wrap each line in its own < p > tag
2. set the max width of its container to force the break where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

remove `<br>`  in beginning of 'remember'  in HTML

Comment: what do i have to remove in the beginning of 'remember'? The only time it says that in my CSS is     <meta name="text:Subtitle" content="Pray you, love,remember.">

Comment: find <br> in HTML and remove it. <br>  is not in css.